# How can the users of my map add their favorite places

Tags: openlayers, database, markers, leaflet-draw

I want to create a map where the users of my website can add their favorite touristic places by clicking on the map and add some attributes.
I don't mind if it's done by Leaflet openlayers or any technology

Edit : I'm still learning but i think i found something about roles and permissions in geoserver that allow only registred users to make changes and edit the map

Here's an example with Mapserver : https://youtu.be/kxshRcjjC_8?t=2m1s

Comment: Use marker and popup using 'overlay' http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html